# Asp.net c# Crystal Printing Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

**Hello Friends
I am using Asp.Net C# & CrystalreportViewer. I developed report in crystal 8.5 and call through crystal report viewer. Everything running fine but when i click print button on top crystal bar it's pop up window which is say that export in pdf and then print from there. So when i click ok it's create pdf file and then i am able to print the document.

Is it any another way that i can open printer selection dialog box and then able to give print directly.

Thanks
kartik**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in more recent versions of Crystal Reports. I can't remember if you can do it in 8.5, I think not.

Can you just use a newer version of Crystal? 8.5 is about 10 years old.